# Hide Tailwindcss error from VS Code, or at least solve it: Tailwind CSS: package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

How I can solve or at least hide some error from Visual Studio Code

[image: Tailwind CSS: package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: package.json]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply press `Esc` to close the error panel.